# delay loading of Excel using COMAddIn

Tags: com, vsto, visual-studio-addins, excel-addins

I have got a question to excel community active here.

I am trying to intercept Excel workbook open event. the scenario is like this:

when a user double click a workbook in windows explorer, before opening the workbook in Excel, I would like to display a dialog box to user if he would like to open the workbook or cancel the open operation. If user clicks "YES" to open the workbook then workbook is loaded in Excel or else Excel window is empty.

Additionally I would like to capture the workbook name before it is actually visible to user.

as per my research, I found that .xls while which are associated with Excel application, Excel takes the file name and passes it to the DDE. the picture between what happens between DDE loads the file and Workbook is actually shown up, is not so clear to me. Is there any way to intercept anything in between DDE loading and workbook shown event in anyway?

So my questions are:

1. can we delay loading of Excel and inject some other program in between so that I could capture the name of workbook before it is actually visible to user.
2. is it possible via COM AddIn?

PS: people might say that its a duplicate question. but it is not.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated?

Comment: write your own program. right click xls files and select your own program as default one and then open xls via your own soft.

Answer (score 0):

```
    this.Application.WorkbookOpen += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);

    void ThisAddIn_WorkbookNewWorkBook(Excel.Workbook Wb)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption",
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.No)
            Wb.Close();
        //write here the code   
    }
```